# Operation with inner array attributes using Aggregation on Spring Data MongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I have the following aggregation working on mongodb, but I not figured out how to replicate it on Spring Data.

```
db.pedido.aggregate( [ 
  { $unwind: "$items" }, 
  { $project: { itemValue: { $multiply: [ "$items.price", "$items.quantity"] } } }, 
  { $group: { _id: "$_id", orderValue: { $sum: "$itemValue" } } }, 
  { $match: { orderValue: { $gte: 150 } } } 
] )
```

I've tried something like this,

```
Aggregation agg = Aggregation.newAggregation(Order.class,
    project("items"),
    unwind("items"),
    project("items.price", "items.quantity").and("items.price").multiply("items.quantity").as("itemValue"),
    group("_id").sum("itemValue").as("orderValue"),
    match(where("orderValue").gte(150))
);
return operations.aggregate(agg, Order.class, Order.class).getMappedResults();
```

but I got the java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid reference 'price'! What's wrong in the Spring Aggregation? There is any way to use the mongodb aggregation with @Query methods, or so other way to do this?

I am using MongoDB 3.2 and spring-data-mongodb 1.9.1.RELEASE

Comment: I have the same problem here. Seems like there's a problem with calling inner item or something.